# What is the Page.ResponseEncoding default value?

Tags: asp.net

I knew that what is the purpose of the [ResponseEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.responseencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And I knew I can set it in the Page directive like below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  ResponseEncoding="UTF-8"  %>
```

But What is the default value of it when it is ignored in the Page directive? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any default value.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.responseencoding%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) says:

> **Remarks:**
>
> **In most circumstances, do not set this property in code.** Set the
> ResponseEncoding attribute to the value you want using the @ Page
> directive in the .aspx file. When the page is requested, the
> dynamically generated class sets the property.

Comment: I know it is what MSDN said . But Shouldn't HTTP Response know how to contains a page's content ?

Comment: @Joe.wang:- I know that you have read the MSDN. I just tried to highlight the point which actually answer your question.

Comment: What I understand from the `Remarks` is No matter whether the `ResponseEncoding` attribute is set explicitly. When the page is requested, the dynamically generated class sets the property. Isn't it ?

Comment: So I think it would be some default value set by dynamically generated class. like int type default value is 0.